# Where can I find project references in VS2017 Azure Function Project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure

I have created an Azure Function project with VS2017 Preview 3.0. Strangely when I added a reference to System.Net.Http, the project compiles and runs fine. But I can not find the assembly reference to System.Net.Http in the project definition. 
[image]

Below is the complete csproj file. I can not find any of the reference here. Is it now defined in a different place?

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs" Version="2.1.0-beta1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions" Version="2.1.0-beta1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http" Version="1.0.0-beta1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus" Version="2.1.0-beta1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="10.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="1.0.0-alpha3" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

I came upon this in order to solve [another problem](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/issues/487)

Edit: updated the screenshot to expand nuget references as well

[image]

Comment: Expand the NuGet subtree.

Comment: It is not in nuget neither. I will update the screen shot

Comment: The WebJobs package pulls in other packages and the result is a large dependency tree of many DLL's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that [System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Net.Http.Formatting.Extension/) is under NuGet packages and System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll use System.Net.Http.dll as one of its Dependencies. It means that once we want to use System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll, the System.Net.Http.dll also will be installed in our project.

[image]

Comment: In my case, it was a direct reference. I am using HttpClient in System.Net.Http.dll. And yet, the reference to System.Net.Http.dll can not be found in the project file.

Comment: Since the System.Net.Http.dll is installed in your project, you could use it directly without install it from NuGet. You can also install it from NuGet manually. After that, you could see the System.Net.Http.dll under NuGet package.

Comment: The reference to System.Net.Http.dll will not be found in the project file unless you install the package manually from NuGet.